# How can I transitionTo a route that includes a model id, from having the id stored in a variable?

Tags: ember.js

Here is my router.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('category', {path: '/category/:category_id'});
  this.route('listing', {path: '/listing/:listing_id'});
});

export default Router;
```

I'm trying to make it so that when the user selects an option from the navbar component, they will be redirected to the appropriate categories/category_id page. I am able to get the right ID into a variable in the navbar component but my this.transitionTo statement does not work. Here is the navbar-header.js:

import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  model() {
     return this.store.findAll('category');
   },
   actions: {
     categorySelected: function(){
       debugger;
       var e = document.getElementById("categories");
       var catId = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
       //I have verified that catId contains the appropriate ID at this point.

       //Where the error happens:
      this.transitionTo('/category/' + catId);
     }
   }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Heads up everyone, you can't do a transitionTo from a component, you have to use an action and send it back to the route. And as joshfarrent said it is supposed to be this.transitionTo('category', catId);

Comment: what is the error you are getting in the console?

Comment: {{#link-to 'category'  category_id}} Link {{/link-to}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the Id as a separate param in the `transitionTo`, and remove the slashes, like this:

```
this.transitionTo('category', catId);
```

See the `transitionTo` section of the Ember Route docs [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_transitionTo).

I'd also recommend against using the HTML element's value to figure out which item has been selected, and rather do something like this on each action helper in your template:

```
{{action "categorySelected" VALUE}}
```

Just replace VALUE with the same numerical value that you were setting on the HTML element. This way, the value of the element will be passed to your `categorySelected` function as follows:

```
categorySelected: function(value) {
   debugger;

   this.transitionTo('category', value);
 }
```

Finally, is there a reason you're not just using a `{{link-to}}` helper to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Thanks, the redirect line ultimately worked, but note: it turns out you can't do a transitionTo directly from a component, you have to use a sendAction and action handler to do the transitionTo from the route. As for why I couldn't just do link-to, it is a drop-down options box.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't spot that it was a component in your original question. Glad it helped!